# Python TypeError: 'BFS' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, search, breadth-first-search

I am currently working on an assignment for which I have a problem which I need to solve using the BFS algorithm. The goal is to implement Breadth First Search and to apply it on my problem board. I currently have the following solution, but am somehow stuck, since I get the error "TypeError: 'BFS' object is not subscriptable". As I am still a beginner in both search algorithms and python programming, every input as to what mistakes I may have made are highly appreciated.

```
from .. problem import Problem
from .. datastructures.queue import Queue


# please ignore this
def get_solver_mapping():
    return dict(bfs=BFS)


class BFS(object):
    # TODO, exercise 1:
    # - implement Breadth First Search (BFS)
    # - use 'problem.get_start_node()' to get the node with the start state
    # - use 'problem.is_end(node)' to check whether 'node' is the node with the end state
    # - use a set() to store already visited nodes
    # - use the 'queue' datastructure that is already imported as the 'fringe'/ the 'frontier'
    # - use 'problem.successors(node)' to get a list of nodes containing successor states
    def solve(self, problem: Problem):
        visited = set() # to keep track of already visited nodes
        queue = [problem]  # queue 
        # queue = [] # creating a queue for visited vertices  
        # we ask the problem to tell as where to start the search
        source_node = problem.get_start_node()
        # setting source node as visited and adding it to the queue  
        visited.add(source_node)
        queue.append(source_node)
        while queue:       # loop as long as there is a queue
            current_node = queue.pop(0)
            print(current_node)
            for neighbour in self[current_node]:
                if neighbour not in visited:
                    visited.append(neighbour)
                    queue.append(neighbour)
        return visited
```

Answer (score 0):

You're running into this issue because of this statement:

```py
for neighbour in self[current_node]:
```

`self` isn't subscriptable, so accessing the index errors out. You just need to replace `self[current_node]` with the correct method to get the adjacency list for the node (which depends on your implementation of the node class, but it usually is something similar to `node.getNeighbours()`).